# Compare method inside class causing an error; NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c

Ok, so i'm building a concordance of a book and everything seems to be working right expect my compare function to either find out if the word is already in my array or not, i made a basic compare function that either return 1, -1, or 0. I know there is a NSComparisonResults but i'm more comfortable with this so far. Anyways i want the function to compare the _wordBeingCatalog to another word in my UniqueWord class, this is what i have in my class that pretty much involves my method

```
 -(instancetype)initWithString:(NSString*)wordBeingCataloged 
                       andline:(NSNumber*)currentLine
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self == nil) return nil;
    _wordBeingCataloged=wordBeingCataloged;
    _count=0;
    _LinenumberWhereWordisFound= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self addALineNumberToCurrentLineNumberArray:currentLine];//This is a function in c++ it looks like addline(currentline); i dont know if i did it right
    return self;

}

-(NSInteger) compareCurrent:(UniqueWord *)word withAnother:(UniqueWord *)text{
  if ([word isGreaterThan:text] )//crashes here
  {
      return 1;
  }

    if([text isGreaterThan:word]){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;

}

-(void) addALineNumberToCurrentLineNumberArray:(NSNumber *)currentLine{
    NSInteger index=[ self newIndexUsing:currentLine];
    ++_count;
    if(index==-1)
        return;
    [_LinenumberWhereWordisFound insertObject:currentLine atIndex:(0+index)];
}
```

When i run my method i cause a

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [UniqueWord compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100201740'
```

My belief is that it is not comparing my two Strings in the Array, instead its comparing something else, can someone please explain the problem i am receiving.

by the way the program stops at the first if statement in the compare function

Answer (score 0):

You do not list the contents of your `isGreaterThan:` function in the `UniqueWord` class, but it must contain a call to `compare:` which is not implemented.

You may also want to consider changing your `compareCurrent:withAnother:` method to use constants.

```
-(NSInteger)compareCurrent:(UniqueWord *)word 
               withAnother:(UniqueWord *)text
{
    if ([word isGreaterThan:text])//crashes here
    {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if([text isGreaterThan:word]) 
    {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```